# Why JsonNode.get("key").asText() is returning empty String

Tags: json, string, format, mapping, objectmapper

I have a problem with saving to playersJson String, data from node "players". Node is created based on json dataJson, created with byte[] playesFile. I suspect that the error is due to incorrect parsing of these strings?

As a result, String playersJson returns an empty String and I would like it to contain information about "players" in json format, which I will then throw into Map<String,Player>

Code fragment:

```
            byte[] playersFile = storageService.downloadFile(FILENAME);
            String dataJson = new String(playersFile);

            try {
                JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(dataJson);
                String playersJson = jsonNode.get("players").asText();
                data = objectMapper.readValue(playersJson, new TypeReference<Map<String, Player>>(){});
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

String dataJson:

```
{
"players":
 [
  {
    "key": "03a2452c-9d6b-47f5-9616-9a6833312762",
    "value": {
              "uuid": "2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3",
              "name": "Artur",
              "elo": 2000,
              "gamesPlayed": 0,
              "email": "arti123i@mail.com"
              }
  },
  {
    "key": "8526db7c-6930-45bf-9ae1-fb93e97ff4ba",
    "value": {
             "uuid": "1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001",
             "name": "Kamil",
             "elo": 2000,
             "gamesPlayed": 0,
             "email": "kamil223@mail.com"
             }
 },
 {
    "key": "5a65ba8c-2180-464b-afe4-69c29b785282",
    "value": {
             "uuid": "b3dc8c98-5759-433e-88cd-0233946b9241",
             "name": "Marek",
             "elo": 3000,
             "gamesPlayed": 0,
             "email": "marek111@mail.com"
             }
 }
],
"games":
  [
   {
    "reportedTime": "2022-07-11T14:43:10.0354202+02:00",
    "reportedBy": {
      "uuid": "2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3",
      "name": "Artur",
      "elo": 2016,
      "gamesPlayed": 1,
      "email": "arti123i@mail.com"
    },
    "result": [
      [
        {
          "player": {
            "uuid": "2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3",
            "name": "Artur",
            "elo": 2016,
            "gamesPlayed": 1,
            "email": "arti123i@mail.com"
          },
          "eloBefore": 2000,
          "eloAfter": 2016
        },
        {
          "player": {
            "uuid": "1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001",
            "name": "Kamil",
            "elo": 2016,
            "gamesPlayed": 1,
            "email": "kamil223@mail.com"
          },
          "eloBefore": 2000,
          "eloAfter": 2016
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "player": {
            "uuid": "b3dc8c98-5759-433e-88cd-0233946b9241",
            "name": "Marek",
            "elo": 2968,
            "gamesPlayed": 1,
            "email": "marek111@mail.com"
          },
          "eloBefore": 3000,
          "eloAfter": 2968
        }
      ]
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL83W.png)

[code debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8BTJ.png)

Comment: Use `jsonNode.get("players").toString()`

Comment: Ok, this worked with playersJson String but then there was a problem with parsing this String to Map<String, Player>. Error goeas like this `Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.String.mkelo.entity.Player> from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY) `

Comment: This exception is raised because you're trying to deserialize a List in a Map. `players` node contains JsonArray.

Comment: playerJson String looks like that `[{"key":"03a2452c-9d6b-47f5-9616-9a6833312762","value":{"uuid":"2ae8d022-e0f4-4502-8e0e-1874997543e3","name":"Artur","elo":2000,"gamesPlayed":0,"email":"arti123i@mail.com"}},{"key":"8526db7c-6930-45bf-9ae1-fb93e97ff4ba","value":{"uuid":"1bb43d73-3f94-40fc-a680-99f4a9304001","name":"Kamil","elo":2000,"gamesPlayed":0,"email":"kamil223@mail.com"}},{"key":"5a65ba8c-2180-464b-afe4-69c29b785282","value":{"uuid":"b3dc8c98-5759-433e-88cd-0233946b9241","name":"Marek","elo":3000,"gamesPlayed":0,"email":"marek111@mail.com"}}]`

Comment: So do you have any ideas how to transform this string to a map with "key" as String and "value" as Player Object ????

Comment: I am no expert in Jackson . You can find solution of this in old similar stack overflow posts .  Like This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70781588/cannot-deserialize-value-of-type-java-util-linkedhashmapjava-lang-string-java

Answer (score 0):

The `asText()` method returns `null` for `Array` or `Object` nodes. As for your example, the value of the "**players**" key, its an object. Hence its returning as an EMPTY String. Instead you can use `toString()`. This would return the value as a **String** for the object value.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jsonnode-astext-vs-tostring

Documentation for Jackson: https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.15.0-rc2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText--